# Api Token response

Tags: kotlin, http, token, response, okhttp

I'm trying to implement a simple API post response
Using the OkHttp library. This is what I was able to try.
is this the correct way? even after logging the messages nothing shows in the console. I saw quite a few guides but couldn't follow them since they were outdated, I would be thankful for any recommendations

````
data class Credentials(val username: String, val password: String)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var usernameEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var passwordEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var loginButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText)
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.button)

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            onApiRequestClick(it)
        }

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Health_textView)
        val fullText = textView.text.toString()
        val colorDark = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.darkBlue)
        val colorLight = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lightBlue)
        val spannableString = SpannableString(fullText)
        spannableString.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(colorLight),
            0, 7,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        spannableString.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(colorDark),
            8,
            fullText.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        textView.text = spannableString
    }

    fun onApiRequestClick(view: View) {
        val username = usernameEditText.text.toString()
        val password = passwordEditText.text.toString()

        val credentials = Credentials(username, password)
        Log.d("Credentials", "Username: ${credentials.username}, Password: ${credentials.password}")

        val url = "https://infomapapp.com/hmcpapi/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate"

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password))
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    Log.d("API Request", "API request failed: ${e.message}")
                }
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val responseBody = response.body?.string()
                runOnUiThread {
                    Log.d("API Response", "API response:\n$responseBody")
                }
            }
        })
    }

}```
````